# Entity Framework: Filtering by multiple conditions on sub table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Lets say there are two tables - Customers and CustomerConfigurations.

Customer contains ID,NAME

CustomConfigurations contains CustomerID, Type(int), Value(int)

I want to get all customers that ALL the following conditions apply to:

1. Has a customerconfiguration row with type=x and value=x1
2. Has a customerconfiguration row with type=y and value=y1
3. Has a customerconfiguration row with type=z and value=z1

You get the point.

What is the best way to achieve such a query with entity framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you mean something like this:

```
dbContext.Customers.Where(cust => 
          cust.CustomerConfigurations.Any(conf => conf.Type==x && conf.Value==x1) && 
          cust.CustomerConfigurations.Any(conf => conf.Type==y && conf.Value==y1) &&
          cust.CustomerConfigurations.Any(conf => conf.Type==z && conf.Value==z1));
```

Comment: Is this the most efficient way to do such a query?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Think about how you would do it in SQL.